# Apendchild only apending once in ForEach method

Tags: javascript

```
function addOrgsToCard(Data) { 
  const orgs = document.getElementById("orgs");
  const org = document.createElement("div");
  org.classList.add("org");
  Data.forEach((organisation)=>{
    org.innerHTML = `
    <div class="org">
    <img src="${organisation.avatar_url}" alt="" />
    <span>${organisation.login}</span>
    </div>
  `;
  console.log(organisation.login);
  orgs.appendChild(org);
  });
  
}
```

This is the function to add organization details in a div of a profile card but the problem is apendchild method is appending only one organisation detail (the last one from the API call) ,Can anyone help me solve this issue?[image]

Comment: What is `Data`?

Comment: Try to declare the org element inside the foreach

Comment: `appendChild` does't clone the element it appends, the element is just moved from a place to another. You've to create/clone the element inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.innerHTML =` overwrites the previous value.
So every time you loop over the data the previous elements get removed.
You should move the creation of your `org` element inside the `forEach` loop:

```js
function addOrgsToCard(Data) { 
  const orgs = document.getElementById("orgs");
  Data.forEach((organisation)=>{
    const org = document.createElement("div");
    org.classList.add("org");
    org.innerHTML = `
    <div class="org">
    <img src="${organisation.avatar_url}" alt="" />
    <span>${organisation.login}</span>
    </div>
    `;
    console.log(organisation.login);
    orgs.appendChild(org);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Try using only "append"(I am not sure if this works).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).